# Creating Constant for section is good Idea?

Tags: swift3, coding-style

I have a tableview which have number of section. lets say first section is for UserProfile. In numberOfRows in section I want to use like

```
if section == UserProfileSection {
  return 2
}
```

is making constant like this is good idea? because UserProfileSection is not going to be use anywhere else. Or should I use directory 0 like this.

```
if section == 0 {
  return 2
}
```

Comment: Yes, a constant is a good idea! And that is 100% opinion-based, therefore off-topic.

Comment: If I make a constant will it increase memory consumption?

Comment: 1. why? 2. do **not** worry about stuff like that!